# Bash Scripting: Can you make a function call itself?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm making a bash script with a simple interactive menu that asks a yes or no question. I'm wondering if I can use a function to call itself and restart the prompt if the person writes random junk, is this possible?

Code:

```
Question () {
read -r -p "yes or no quesiotn [Y/N]"
Response

case Response in
    Y|y)
        #some code
        ;;
    N|n)
        #more code
        ;;
    *) 
        ehco "im sorry i didnt catch that"
        Question
        ;;
    esac
}

Question
```

Comment: Yes, but you'll get better results if you don't misspell `echo` (and users will be less unhappy if you don't misspell `question`, etc).  Why didn't you try it?  And why do you think (tail) recursion is better than iteration?

Comment: Recursion is allowed, but not recommended in this case. A loop is more efficient.

Comment: sorry about the poor spelling, and I don't have a way to test it at the moment, thank you very much. Also, what's iteration/recursion (sorry I'm new to coding in general).

Comment: @gomilksolgo Iteration is loops, like `while true; do ... ; done` and `for var in ...; do ...; done`. Recursion is when a function calls itself, look it up in Wikipedia.

Comment: Recursion is best used when the algorithm involves combining a computation on the current data with a simpler reduction of the data. For instance, `factorial(n) = n * factorial(n-1)` (until you get to `n = 0`). If there's no reduction, use a loop.

Comment: @chepner how would I use a loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of calling itself, make the function return appropriate exit codes, (a `1` for failed, a `0` for success), then have a do-nothing `until` loop do the work:

```
Question () {
            read -r -p "Yes or no question [Y/N]?" Response
            case "$Response" in
                 Y|y)
                     #some code
                     ;;
                 N|n)
                     #more code
                     ;;
                 *) 
                     echo "I'm sorry I didn't catch that."
                     return 1
                     ;;
            esac
            }


until Question ; do : ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

While you can use recursion in this case, it's not recommended because you'll consume memory (to track the function calls) for each bad response. Instead, just use a loop.

```
while true; do
    read -r -p "yes or no question [Y/N] " response
    case "$response" in
        Y|y)
          # some code
          ;;
        N|n)
          # more code
          ;;
        *) echo "please provide a valid response"
           continue ;;
    esac
    break
done
```